# Codemagic flutter build ipa --export-method ad-hoc error: requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature

Tags: flutter, continuous-integration, code-signing, codemagic

I'm using Codemagic to set up a CI/CD but iOS build give me this error:

```
Building ad-hoc IPA...                                              3.2s
Encountered error while creating the IPA:
error: exportArchive: "Runner.app" requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature.

Try distributing the app in Xcode: "open /Users/builder/clone/build/ios/archive/Runner.xcarchive"
cp: build/ios/ipa/qshoot.ipa: No such file or directory
```

I've added all needed variables in the code magic and this is mu workflow:

```
...
      - name: Set up keychain to be used for code signing using Codemagic CLI 'keychain' command
        script: keychain initialize
      - name: Set up Provisioning profiles from environment variables
        script: |
          PROFILES_HOME="$HOME/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles"
          mkdir -p "$PROFILES_HOME"
          PROFILE_PATH="$(mktemp "$PROFILES_HOME"/$(uuidgen).mobileprovision)"
          echo ${CM_PROVISIONING_PROFILE} | base64 --decode > "$PROFILE_PATH"
          echo "Saved provisioning profile $PROFILE_PATH"      
      - name: Set up signing certificate
        script: |
          echo $CM_CERTIFICATE | base64 --decode > /tmp/certificate.p12
          if [ -z ${CM_CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD+x} ]; then
            # when using a certificate that is not password-protected
            keychain add-certificates --certificate /tmp/certificate.p12
          else
            # when using a password-protected certificate
            keychain add-certificates --certificate /tmp/certificate.p12 --certificate-password $CM_CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD
          fi      
      - name: Set up code signing settings on Xcode project
        script: xcode-project use-profiles
      ...

      - flutter build ipa --export-method ad-hoc $DART_DEFINES
```

also my provising profile has the notification feature as you can see:
[image: Provisioning Profile]

and here is the machine log for `xcode-project use-profiles`

```
Configure code signing settings
Searching for files matching /Users/builder/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/*.mobileprovision
Searching for files matching /Users/builder/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/*.provisionprofile
List available code signing certificates in keychain /Users/builder/Library/codemagic-cli-tools/keychains/04-08-22_urm65p2u.keychain-db
Searching for files matching /Users/builder/clone/**/*.xcodeproj
Completed configuring code signing settings
 - Using profile "Ben" [***] for target "Runner" [Debug] from project "Runner"
 - Using profile "Ben" [***] for target "Runner" [Profile] from project "Runner"
 - Using profile "Ben" [***] for target "Runner" [Release] from project "Runner"
Generated options for exporting the project
 - Method: ad-hoc
 - Provisioning Profiles:
     - [APPLICATION-BUNDLE-ID]: Ben
 - Signing Certificate: Apple Distribution
 - Signing Style: manual
 - Team Id: [TEAM-ID]
Saved export options to /Users/builder/export_options.plist
```

Comment: can you add output from `xcode-project use-profiles` step?

Comment: @MikhailTokarev I edited the question and added the output